# How long are Grails versions supported?

Tags: grails

How long is a specific version of Grails supported? The general VMWare support policy appears to be to support the current release and one release back. I haven’t been able to find any Grails specific information on how long releases are supported, does the general VMWare policy apply?

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the Apache-licensed open source version, the license states:

> Disclaimer of Warranty. Unless required by applicable law or
>   agreed to in writing, Licensor provides the Work (and each
>   Contributor provides its Contributions) on an "AS IS" BASIS,
>   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
>   implied, including, without limitation, any warranties or conditions
>   of TITLE, NON-INFRINGEMENT, MERCHANTABILITY, or FITNESS FOR A
>   PARTICULAR PURPOSE. You are solely responsible for determining the
>   appropriateness of using or redistributing the Work and assume any
>   risks associated with Your exercise of permissions under this License.

For paid support, you should contact Springsource: http://www.springsource.com/support/groovyandgrailssupport